# Amazon s3 transfer utility not working in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have to upload a large file like more then 4gb onto amazon s3. amazon sdk giving two options for uploading and downloading from s3. one is awss3transfermanager and other is awss3transferutility. i actually want to use awss3transferutility because i want the app to continue uploading in background.  awss3transferutility has two functions  uploadFile and other uploadFileUsingMultiPart . uploadFile function actually works in background but uploading starts from 0 on network changes or drop. For that reason i am curretly using uploadFileUsingMultiPart function so the uploading won't get restart from 0 on networks fail. but this  uploadFileUsingMultiPart function won't continue uploading in background. In their latest release they introduce this uploadFileUsingMultiPart function inside awstransferutility. so i was expecting that uploading will continue in background with network fail but it won't continue in background. i just wanted to ask is it sdk related bug or i am doing something wrong

this is the code i am curretly

//in app delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    [AWSS3TransferUtility interceptApplication:application
           handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:identifier
                             completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

// in ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    expression = [AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadExpression new];
    expression.progressBlock = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadTask *  task, NSProgress *  progress) {
       typeof(self) newWeakSelf = weakSelf;

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           // Do something e.g. Alert a user for transfer completion.

           NSLog(@"progress value %f",progress.fractionCompleted);
           // On failed uploads, `error` contains the error object.
           newWeakSelf->progressView.progress = progress.fractionCompleted;
       });
   };

   completionHandler = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadTask *task, NSError *error) {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           NSLog(@"uploading completed ");
       });
   };


   AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"us-west-1:7a24b199-e4b2-4657-9627-sdfs4ssdff"];
   AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
   // AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

   AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration *tfConfig = [AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration new];
   tfConfig.retryLimit = 5;
   tfConfig.multiPartConcurrencyLimit = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3];
   [AWSS3TransferUtility registerS3TransferUtilityWithConfiguration:configuration transferUtilityConfiguration:tfConfig forKey:@"transfer-utility-with-advanced-options"];

   transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility S3TransferUtilityForKey:@"transfer-utility-with-advanced-options"];
}

-(void)startUploading {
    NSString *filePath =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileURL =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSString *fileContentTypeStr = @"video/mp4";

    //  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    //  AWSTask *task = [transferUtility uploadDataUsingMultiPart:data bucket:@"sibme-development" key:@"temp/testfilenew/testfile1.mp4" contentType:fileContentTypeStr expression:expression completionHandler:completionHandler ];

    AWSTask *task = [transferUtility uploadFileUsingMultiPart:fileURL bucket:@"development" key:@"temp/testfilenew/testfile.mp4" contentType:fileContentTypeStr expression:expression completionHandler:completionHandler];

    [task continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask * _Nonnull t) {
        if (t.result) {
          self->uplaodTask = t.result;
        }
        return nil;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on this, but I noticed something in your code - Bucket region:

initWithRegionType:AWSRegion**USEast1**
identityPoolId:@**"us-west-1**:...

Once  I had similar mismatch in my code, the bucket region and the Cognito identity pool region did not match, and that was causing problems. This may or may not be the case in your code, but just adding some info based on my experience.

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"us-west-1:7a24b199-e4b2-4657-9627-sdfs4ssdff"];
   AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think there is a bug with the SDK, you can try with the latest version of the SDK and if you are still seeing issues, open an Issue over in https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios with some repro steps.